# Is there a "Disperse Markers" option in Mapbox GL-JS?

Tags: point, overlapping-features, mapbox-gl-js

I have used the "Disperse Markers" tool in ArcGIS before, but I am currently working on a project where I am using Mapbox GL-JS to display point data. Many of my points overlap, and I would like them to all be completely visible. This would be possible with "Disperse Markers" in ArcGIS or "Point Displacement" in QGIS.

Here's a link to the ArcGIS tool explanation: https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2008/08/01/how-to-scatter-marker-symbols-for-stacked-or-clustered-point-features/